# Not able to access kubernetes cluster service on a taint node

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-alertmanager

I have tried to deploy alertmanager service on a taint node by defining tolerations explicityl.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alertmanager
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alertmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      name: alertmanager
      labels:
        app: alertmanager
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: "prometheusnew"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "false"
        effect: "NoExecute"
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: placement_affinity
                operator: In
                values:
                - prometheusnew
      containers:
      - name: alertmanager
        image: prom/alertmanager:v0.15.3
        args:
          - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
          - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
        ports:
        - name: alertmanager
          containerPort: 9093
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/alertmanager
        - name: alertmanager
          mountPath: /alertmanager
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: alertmanager
      - name: alertmanager
        emptyDir: {}
```

The cluster ip 172.30.148.104 is accessible from the same node but the pods and service ip is not accessible from any other nodes or pods in different node.

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
alertmanager   ClusterIP   172.30.148.104   <none>        9093/TCP   20m
```

Pods are running fine and if deploy without taint tolerations it works fine.
Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Is the alertmanager pod running?

Comment: Yes it is running. I am able to connect and curl from the same node pods.

Comment: Do you have an `externalTrafficPolicy` set to `local` in your service?

Comment: @yyyyahir No, I did not set it explicitly in service definition file.

Comment: You didn't set it explicitly but is it on? `kubectl get svc alertmanager -o yaml`. The `externalTrafficPolicy` can prevent your requests from being forwarded to other nodes in the cluster.